# nginx redirect old URL to new URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

We just updated all our product url to new url. It only add some letter in the URL.
An example

old URL:

```
http://www.example.com/parent/children/product.html
```

new URL:

```
http://www.example.com/new-parent/children/product.html
```

(just added "new-" in "parent")

I try with this but not work.

```
location /parent {
    rewrite ^/parent(.*) http://$server_name/new-parent$1 permanent;
}
```

So anyone can help me to correct this redirection?

Comment: "Not work" is bad description of problem. You should describe what happens. Also show full server config

Comment: Hi Alexey. I mean old URL did not redirect to new URL, thanks

Comment: What word of "show full config" is not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put `rewrite ^/parent(.*) http://$server_name/new-parent$1 permanent;` into `server` directive, not into `/parent` location.